# Compare two Datetime type ("MMMM-yyyy) in SQL Server CE

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have to compare two records only by theirs Date parts (month-year),

I used to compare

```
 WHERE MonthAndYear >= '" + StartDate + "'  AND MonthAndYear <= '" + CustomEndDate + "'
```

In example

- MonthAndYear is also MMMM-yyyy type
- StartDate is April-2013,
- and CustomEndDate is April-2016.

  It returns only April-2013,April-2014,April-2015 only. I want to get all month-year in the range.

Comment: If this kind of query runs often and needs to be performant, it is grounds for considering splitting your date into its component fields. _Preferably by means of an indexed view with calculated columns._

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert your MonthAndYear to datetime and then compare
Like:

`WHERE CAST('01-'+MonthAndYear AS DATETIME) >=  @StartDate   AND 
  DATEADD(mm, 1, CAST('01-'+ MonthAndYear AS DATETIME))-1 <= @CustomEndDate`

Answer (score 0):

You can try a little trick:

```
WHERE YEAR(MonthAndYear)>=YEAR('" + StartDate + "') AND MONTH(MonthAndYear)>=MONTH('" + StartDate + "') 
AND YEAR(MonthAndYear)<=YEAR('" + CustomEndDate + "') AND MONTH(MonthAndYear)<=MONTH('" + CustomEndDate  + "')
```

UPDATE: or use DATEPART function if YEAR and MONTH are not available in SQL CE

Comment: But In the SQL CE we cannot run this type queries. Like YEAR(), Month()

Comment: In this case you can replace YEAR and MONTH with 
 [DATEPART Function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173998%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Alexej ,i will try on that.

Comment: @SandunTharaka, please mark as answer or helpful if it works

Comment: In you mention answer not work in SQL CE, but it work you mention in the comment, DATEPART Function .